ASP.NET MVC : display image on view
I am trying to display an image in a view.
Here I add an image in SQL Server Express (price is defined as int and picture is a varbinary(MAX) column):
insert into products (price, picture) 
    select 499, BulkColumn 
    from Openrowset(Bulk 'C:\Users\tally\Pictures\harddisk-275-183.jpg', Single_Blob) as img

Here I have defined properties:
public class ProductsModel
{
    public Image ProductImage { get; set; }
    public int ProductPrice { get; set; }
}

I get the data from the database using this controller method:
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult Products(ProductsModel objProductsModel)
{
    string conStr = "Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS; Initial Catalog=Onlineproducts; Integrated Security=True";

    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conStr);
    con.Open();

    SqlDataAdapter dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(new SqlCommand("select * from products", con));
    DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
    dataAdapter.Fill(dataSet);

    if (dataSet.Tables[0].Rows.Count == 1)
    {
        Byte[] data = new Byte[0];
        data = (Byte[])(dataSet.Tables[0].Rows[0]["picture"]);
        MemoryStream mem = new MemoryStream(data);
        objProductsModel.ProductImage = Image.FromStream(mem);

        objProductsModel.ProductPrice = Convert.ToInt32(dataSet.Tables[0].Rows[0]["price"]);
        return View(objProductsModel);
    }

    return View(objProductsModel);
}

Here I try to display both image and price in the view:
@model Nettbutikk.Models.ProductsModel

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/products.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <p><h1>Products</h1></p>
    <hr />

        <div class="responsive">
            <div class="gallery">

                <div>@Html.DisplayFor(ProductsModel => ProductsModel.ProductImage)</div>

                <div class="desc">Kr @Html.DisplayFor(ProductsModel => ProductsModel.ProductPrice)</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>

Price is displayed on webpage as it should be but the image is not.
Maybe to display the image I should select something else than DisplayFor(...)? Please help me.

You cannot display an image using DisplayFor like that, easiest to create a separate request. Create a separate controller action that returns the raw image data, then call said action with Html.Content() (or just a regular img tag).

Thanks for your comments. May be you have code example.

I don't, but try it and post what you try in your question, we will help you fix any problems.

The issue is solved. I added a new Action method in Controller:
public ActionResult GetImage(int id)
{
    string conStr = "Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS; Initial Catalog=Nettbutikk; Integrated Security=True";
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conStr);
    con.Open();

    SqlDataAdapter dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(new SqlCommand("select * from products", con));
    DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
    dataAdapter.Fill(dataSet);

    
    Byte[] data = new Byte[0];
    data = (Byte[])(dataSet.Tables[0].Rows[0]["picture"]);
       
    return File(data, "image/jpg");
}

and then calling this method in View:
<img src="@Url.Action("GetImage", new { id = 1 })" alt="Northern Lights" width="600" height="400">

